# codeigniter declaring a class in to one variable

Tags: php, codeigniter

i am trying to use `$admin->function()` instead `$this->admin_model->function()` 
when i tried to declare a `variable` `$admin=new Admin_model;` in `constructor` and use it in other functions it gives error.. 
my code is given below, i don't know much about `OOP` concept, somebody please help.

```
class Admin extends CI_Controller {
    var $admin;
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('admin_model');
        $admin=new Admin_model;
    }
    public function index($value='')
    {
        if(!$admin->is_admin_logged_in()){
            redirect('admin/login?r='.urlencode(current_url()));
        }
        $data['loggedin']=TRUE;
        $data['account']=$this->session->all_userdata();
        $this->load->view('pages/admin-home',isset($data)?$data:NULL);

    }
}
```

presently i am using this method

`public function login()// this function belongs to the same controller mentioned above
    {
        $r=isset($_GET['r'])?urldecode($_GET['r']):'admin';
        $admin=new Admin_model;
        if($admin->is_admin_logged_in()) redirect($r);
       }`

i don't want declare `$admin=new Admin_model;` in every single function and want to make the code look good and clean, so don't like to use `$this->admin` or `$this->admin_model` either.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to give an alias to a model (as what I can see)

All you have to do is:

```
class Admin extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('admin_model', 'admin');
    }
    public function index($value='')
    {
        if(!$this->admin->is_admin_logged_in()){
            redirect('admin/login?r='.urlencode(current_url()));
        }
        $data['loggedin']=TRUE;
        $data['account']=$this->session->all_userdata();
        $this->load->view('pages/admin-home',isset($data)?$data:NULL);

    }
}
```

Notice where the alias of the model is given

```
$this->load->model('admin_model', 'admin');
```

And how it is used

```
if(!$this->admin->is_admin_logged_in()){
```

Comment: you did not understood what i was trying to say my be the question was confusing, i have updated the question, kindly have a look.

Comment: i did, but as previously mentioned, don't want to use `$this`. please go through the question once again...

Comment: it always uses this because it denotes that the variable is belonging to the class. The thing that I understand about what you want is that you want to create an alias of the model so that whenever you change the model name you don't need to go thru all the codes to change **$this->admin_model->function()**. The code i've provided for you "creates an alias of the model given and this alias can be used throughout the whole controller.

So instead of **$this->admin_model->function()**

all you have to do is **$this->alias->function()** , and yes it should always contain a $this.